# Best approach to transform Dataset[Row] to RDD[Array[String]] in Spark-Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

I am creating a spark Dataset by reading a csv file. Further, I need to transform this Dataset[Row] to RDD[Array[String]] for passing it to the FpGrowth(Spark MLLIB).

```
val df: DataFrame = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/path/to/csv")
val ds: Dataset[Row] = df.groupBy("user").agg(collect_set("values"))
```

Now, I need to select the column "*values*" and transform the resultant dataset to **RDD[Array[String]]**.

```
val rddS: RDD[String] = ds.select(concat_ws(",", col("values")).as("items")).distinct().rdd.map(_.mkString(","))
val rddArray: RDD[Array[String]] = rddS.map(s => s.trim.split(','))
```

I tried out this approach but not sure if its the best way. Please suggest me a optimal way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using toSeq approach

```
val rddArray: RDD[Array[String]] = ds.select("values").rdd.map(r => r.getSeq[String](0).toArray)
```

This was more efficient (faster) for my usecase.

Answer (score 5):

One-liner:

```
val rddArray: RDD[Array[String]] = ds.select("values").as[Array[String]].rdd
```

By the way I'd suggest using dataframe-based Spark ML instead of RDD-based Spark MLLib which is now deprecated. You can use `org.apache.spark.ml.fpm.FPGrowth`.

Comment: Thanks @mck. This worked perfectly for me. I had to use encoder as well.
`ds.select("values").as[Array[String]](ExpressionEncoder(): Encoder[Array[String]]).rdd`

i will also checkout the Spark ML FpGrowth. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use as below, You will reduce the `concat_ws` and `split` operation.

```
val rddS:RDD[Array[String]] = ds.select("values")
    .distinct()
    .rdd.map(r => r.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[String]](0).toArray)
```